# Redux issue when set userId while login

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, next.js13

I'm trying react redux and I'm stuck here so actually when I hit login I am storing data.userid to the reducer and in booking I am trying to access user id but unfortunately I am getting null I hope someone answers this question in explaining way. I feel that I'm able to store the
Below is my code attached.

login.js

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'; // Import useDispatch
import Link from 'next/link';
import { login } from '../utils/api';
import { setUserId } from '../redux/slices/authSlice'; 

const handleLogin = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        try {
            if (!username || !password) {
                alert('Please enter username and password');
                return;
            }
            const response = await login(username, password);
            const data = await response.json();

            dispatch(setUserId(data.userId));

            window.location.href = '/';
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Login failed:', error);
            // Handle login failure (display error message, etc.)
        }
    };
```

authSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
    userId: null,
    isAuthenticated: false,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setUserId(state, action) {
            state.userId = action.payload;
            state.isAuthenticated = true;
        },
        logout(state) {
            state.userId = null;
            state.isAuthenticated = false;
        },
    },
});

export const { setUserId, logout } = authSlice.actions;

export const selectUserId = (state) => state.auth.userId;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

booking.js

```
mport { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'; // Import useDispatch and useSelector
import { fetchSlotById, confirmBooking } from '../../utils/api';

const Booking = () => {
    const availableSlots = useSelector((state) => state.slots);
    const [selectedSlot, setSelectedSlot] = useState(null);
     const userId = useSelector((state) => state.auth.userId);
    const router = useRouter();
    const { id } = router.query;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    console.log(userId, 'booking'); // Here im getting userId as null
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues identified:

Upon successfully fetching data and dispatching, the page is reloaded, causing all data stored in Redux to be null due to the page refresh.
After dispatching, it's essential to ensure that all Redux providers are persisted.

To resolve these issues:

Implement Redux **persistence** to retain data across page reloads.
Explore alternative methods to **avoid the need for page reloading**, ensuring that data remains intact without requiring a page refresh.

Comment: I have commented the window.href and tried to log state there itself. Still im having null. value

Comment: please persist your redux provider 
you can read about in this link  https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist